# hreflang with session based language detection

Tags: seo, google-search-console, language, hreflang, url-parameters

Google's Webmaster Tools reporting that I have pages with missing backlinks.

I provide two languages at my website:
German and English.

A user can switch languages via menu (there are flags of both languages, which can be clicked on by a user). The default language is German.

German page hreflang:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="/blog?lang=de_DE">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/blog?lang=en_GB">
```

English page hreflang:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="/blog?lang=de_DE">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/blog?lang=en_GB">
```

A user visits my blog and uses URI `/blog`. He will get the German version of the page. Then he clicks on the English flag to switch languages to English: `/blog?lang=en_GB`.
If he now navigates to another page f.e `/about-us`, the query parameter is omitted (the information which language the user wants to use is saved via PHP-Session). So if he visits the blog-page again, he will use the `/blog` URI.

Problem: If a user has switched to f.e. English language the URI might be `/blog` OR `/blog?lang=en_GB`. If he switched to the German page the URI might be `/blog` OR `/blog?lang=de_DE`. But only meta tags (hreflang) for the `/blog?lang=LANGUAGECODE` are existing (as shown above), not for the `/blog`-version. This leads to "There are no or wrong backlinks for page /blog"-errors within Google'e Webmaster Tools. How can I solve that problem? I cannot use a conical tag to `/blog` because it can be English or German depending which language the user has selected previously.

Comment: Serving different content under the same URL is a bad practice. Can you change this? The best practice is to always have the language tag in the URL (e.g., `/de/blog` and `/en/blog`).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try to modify my framework accordingly to prepend all my URIs with `/de` or `/en`. So, there is no way to tell Google about that problem?